# Can we use add time to the PHP date() function?

Tags: php, date, increment, hour

I am trying to make a schedule from the current hour
to 12 hours afterwards. I am using the date() function
to retrieve the current time but how can I increment the 
hours and adjust the AM/PM? Can I just add 1 to the date()
function?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$now = time();
$then = $now + 12 * 60 * 60;
echo date(format, $then);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime`:

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hour')); // one hour since now
```

or

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('2011-02-25 14:00:42'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mydate = date("dateformat", time() + 43200);
```

time() gets the current timestamp, then you add 43200 which is 12 hours * 60 mins * 60 secs